# Import Multiple Different .txt Files to SQL Server from a Folder

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I found so many queries online to import multiple files to SQL Server into one single table from a folder like the one below but no help online on how to insert multiple different files as different tables in SQL Server. I have 21 files (21 for now, might increase with time) and its really very tedious to import each and every file from the folder.

```
CREATE TABLE ALLFILENAMES(WHICHPATH VARCHAR(255),WHICHFILE varchar(255))

--some variables
declare @filename varchar(255),
        @path     varchar(255),
        @sql      varchar(8000),
        @cmd      varchar(1000)


--get the list of files to process:
SET @path = 'C:\Users\atp1lip\Desktop\09242017\'
SET @cmd = 'dir ' + @path + '*.txt /b'
INSERT INTO  ALLFILENAMES(WHICHFILE)
EXEC Master..xp_cmdShell @cmd
UPDATE ALLFILENAMES SET WHICHPATH = @path where WHICHPATH is null


--cursor loop
declare c1 cursor for SELECT WHICHPATH,WHICHFILE FROM ALLFILENAMES where WHICHFILE like '%.txt%'
open c1
fetch next from c1 into @path,@filename
While @@fetch_status <> -1
  begin

   set @sql = 'BULK INSERT test FROM ''' + @path + @filename + ''' '
       + '     WITH ( 
               FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', 
               ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
            ) '
print @sql
exec (@sql)

  fetch next from c1 into @path,@filename
  end
close c1
deallocate c1
```

I was wondering if its possible to do this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you also can use function xp_dirtree like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE #FilesList(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), FileName VARCHAR(1000),Depth INT,isFile INT)
    INSERT INTO #FilesList
    EXEC xp_dirtree @FilePath, 1, 1
```